A quick way to verify whether two semidirect products are isomorphic.
This question arises from my classifying groups $G$ of order $4r$ where $r\geqslant5$ is a prime. Let $r=\begin{cases}p\equiv1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)\\q\equiv3\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)\end{cases}$. Let $T\in\mathrm{Syl}_2(G),R\in\mathrm{Syl}_r(G)$. Since $\gcd(|T|,|R|)=1$, $T\cap R=1$. Then by order consideration, $|G|=|T||R|$, so $G=TR$. By Sylow's Theorem, $\begin{cases}n_r\equiv1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ r)\\n_r\mid4r/r=4\end{cases}$, so $n_r=1$, namely $R\unlhd G$, i.e., $G=R\rtimes T$, that is, the short exact sequence $1\xrightarrow{}R\xrightarrow{}G\xrightarrow{}T\xrightarrow{}1$ splits. Let $\varphi:T\to\mathbf{Aut}(R)=\mathbf{Aut}(Z_r)\cong Z_{r-1}$ be a homomorphism and $G=R\rtimes_{\varphi}T$.
Since $|T|=4$, either $T\cong\mathbf{K}_4$ the Klein $4$-group or $T\cong Z_4$ the cyclic group of order $4$.
Consider the case that $r=p\equiv1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$ and $T\cong\mathbf{K}_4=\{1,a,b,c\}$. Since $p-1\equiv0\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$, $\mathbf{Aut}(P)\cong Z_{p-1}=Z_{4k}$ for some integer $k$. Then writing the abelian groups additively as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &\ \mathbf{Hom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(\mathbf{K}_4,Z_{4k})
 \\\cong&\ \mathbf{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/4k\mathbb{Z})
 \\\cong&\ \mathbf{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/4k\mathbb{Z})\oplus\mathbf{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/4k\mathbb{Z})
 \\\cong&\ \{0_1,\varphi_1:\bar1\mapsto2k\}\oplus\{0_2,\varphi_2:\bar1\mapsto2k\},
\end{aligned}
$$
where $0_1,0_2$ represent the trivial homomorphism from the $1^{\text{st}},2^{\text{nd}}$ components of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/4k\mathbb{Z}$ respectively. so $\varphi$ has four choices: $0_1\oplus0_2,0_1\oplus\varphi_2,\varphi_1\oplus0_2,\varphi_1\oplus\varphi_2$.
Although I have known all these possible cases, I need additionally check that whether the semidirect products resulting from all these $\varphi$'s are isomorphic, is there a quick way to do this?

The isomorphism problem is undecidable in general.

@Shaun Yes, but I think my example may be special: [1] It is a semidirect product of two abelian groups. [2] It is a semidirect product of two groups of relatively prime orders.

Prove that any group with a normal subgroup of order a prime $r$ with quotient the Klein $4$-group is isomorphic to $D_{2r}\times C_2$, where $D_{2r}$ is the dihedral group of order $2r$.

(Or is $C_r\times C_2\times C_2$, of course.)

@DavidA.Craven Thanks for your hint, let me have a try.

For semidirect products, you can prove the following lemma, which is an exercise:

$R \rtimes_{\varphi} T \cong R \rtimes_{\varphi \circ f} T$ for all $f \in Aut(T)$.

Now you can use this to see that for $\varphi$ equal $0_1\oplus\varphi_2,\varphi_1\oplus0_2,\varphi_1\oplus\varphi_2$ in your question you get isomorphic groups.

Thanks! This is what I want. And is there any restriction to $R$ and $T$, or just holds for any groups?

No restriction, it works for all groups (also infinite groups).

Thanks, I use the map $\begin{cases}\sigma:H\rtimes_{\varphi}K\to H\rtimes_{\varphi\circ f}K\\sigma:hk\mapsto hf^{-1}(k)\end{cases}$ to construct the isomorphism successfully.
